# How to take a specified number of lines as input?

Tags: c++, string

`cin>>string` takes input until space or new line. But `getline(cin,string)` takes input until new line. Again, `getline(cin,string,'c')` takes input until 'c'. Is there any way to ignore a few `'\n'` character and take a specified number of lines as input?

I tried the code below but it didn't work

```
int main()
{
   string a;
   for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
       getline(cin,a);//take string input 
   }
   cout<<a;
}
```

here for the following input

```
 ksafj kfaskjf(\n)1st
 uuiiuo akjfksad(\n)2nd
 ksafj kasfj(\n)3rd
 asdfed kkkl(\n) when the 4th enter comes input terminate
```

string `a` only holds `"asdfed kkkl"`. I want it to hold all the characters, including the end-of-lines (`\n`).

Comment: Do you want the string to contain the newline characters?

Comment: yes.but a specified number of newline like 8 newlines

Answer (score 10):

Do you want to get the first n lines?

```
std::string get_n_lines(std::istream& input, const std::size_t n)
{
  std::ostringstream result;
  std::string line;
  std::size_t i = 0;

  while (std::getline(input, line) && i < n)
  {
    result << line << '\n';
    ++i
  }

  return result.str();
}

std::string first_4_lines = get_n_lines(std::cin, 4);
```